# Timer for alarm

Tags: c#, timer

I want to make a simple program to make it run in the specific time. Here is my code:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Alarm ft = new Alarm(dateTimePicker1.Value);
    }
}

public class Alarm
{
    public Timer reminder = new Timer();
    public DateTime RemindAt;

    public Alarm(DateTime time)
    {
        RemindAt = time;

        reminder.Interval = (int)(RemindAt - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
        reminder.Start();
        reminder.Tick += new EventHandler(reminder_Tick);
    }

    void reminder_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RemindAt <= DateTime.Now)
        {
            reminder.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show("W: " + RemindAt.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy, HH:mm:ss") + "\n" + "N: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy, HH:mm:ss") + "\n\n");
        }
    }
```

As you can seem I use timers, but it seems pretty inaccurate, I have no idea why. Here is the screenshot of 6 alarms: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGzIh.png

Half of them are wrong. W stands for when it should work, N stands for now. The difference can be huge sometimes, why is that? How to fix that, or maybe there is a better way to make a simple alarm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`s aren't precise, especially for large numbers. Instead of calculating the value for `Interval`, set it to something constant, say `1000`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to set timer interval to 1000, but it seems wrong to check it every second. I wanted a better way, so I came up with this code, which doesn't work properly.

Comment: @irondsd: Don't worry, once every second won't hurt your processor, even if it does seem a little hackish. (Unless you run it for several weeks, then maybe it does seem a little wrong. But then why aren't you using the Task Scheduler? `taskschd.msc`)

Answer (score 0):

Take a Look at [Windows Task Schedular](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Basically create your EXE and let Windows handle the time to run.

[How to do it via UI](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Schedule-a-task)

[Install it Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135821/windows-task-schedular-installer)